# For each $p\in\mathbb{R}$, determine convergence of series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^n \cdot (\sqrt{7n+1}-\sqrt{7n})^p$, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $x_n=\sqrt{7n+1}-\sqrt{7n}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. For each parameter value $p\in\mathbb{R}$, determine whether the series
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{ +\infty }(-1)^n\left(x_n\right)^p$$
is:

1. convergent,
2. absolutely convergent,
3. conditionally convergent.
   The solution to this problem can be divided into 3 cases:

When $p = 0$, we have the series $\sum_{n = 1}^{ +\infty }(-1)^n$, and it seems that it is neither convergent nor absolutely convergent nor conditionally convergent. 
When $p > 0$, using the Leibniz criterion, if $x_n$ is monotonic (and it seems to be strictly decreasing) and tends to $0$ (which is easy to prove), then the series is conditionally convergent. 
When $p < 0$, also using the Leibniz criterion, we can observe that in this case,
$ \frac{1}{ x_n}  \rightarrow  \infty $ (easy to prove). Therefore, the series is neither convergent, nor absolutely convergent, nor conditionally convergent.

Am I thinking good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to write $$\sqrt{7n+1}-\sqrt{7n} = \frac{7n+1-7n}{\sqrt{7n+1}+\sqrt{7n}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{7n+1}+\sqrt{7n}}.$$ Now if $p\le 0$, this the summand will not go to zero as $n\to\infty$, so the sum diverges by the divergence test.

If $p>0$, the sum converges by the alternating series test, since the summands go monotonically to zero and alternate sign.

In the case the $p>0$, we have $$\frac{1}{(\sqrt{7n+1}+\sqrt{7n})^p} \sim \frac{1}{(2\sqrt{7n})^p} = \frac{1}{(2\cdot 7^{p/2}) n^{p/2}} \,\,\,\, \text{ as } \,\,\, n \to \infty$$ Thus, upon taking absolute values, the sum is comparable via the limit comparison test to (a constant multiple of) $$\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{1}{n^{p/2}}$$ which converges if $p>2$ and diverges otherwise. Hence, the sum converges absolutely when $p>2$.

Comment: OK. Thank you very much! I understand for $p\le 0$. But don't fully understand for $p > 0$. Why does $\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{1}{n^{p/2}}$ converges absolutely when $p > 2$ and diverges otherwise? 
And also, there was a $(-1)^n$ in task, but why you don't give attention to it? (I understand that it was intentional, but why)

Comment: This is what absolute convergence means: by definition, we say that $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely if $\sum \vert a_n \vert$ converges, so you want to consider the same sum but take the absolute value of the summands, and the absolute value of $(-1)^n$ is always just $1$. The series $\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac 1 {n^s}$ famously converges if and only if $s > 1$. Here, we have the same sum but with exponent $p/2$ so we need $p/2 > 1$ which is the same as $p>2$.